# Unwanted "margin" between adjacent background-colored divs

Tags: html, css, background, margin

I am trying to code a special background that keeps himself centered on screen. So I used div and pseudo elements to do so, but I keep getting a undesired "margin" between my divs and their pseudo elements, specially in small screen devices.

**Screenshot from my phone showing some white undesired margins**

[image]

Any idea on how to prevent this 'margins'?

Thank you very much!

```css
*,*:after,*:before,body{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
.row{width:100%;display:inline-flex}
.cont1920{width:100%;max-width:1920px;float:left;margin:auto;background:#8dbb70;position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.artw{width:1920px;position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-960px}
.h23{height:910.77px}

.rec2,.rec3{position:relative;background:#3F7F7D;content:''}
.rec2{width:631.10px;height:441.33px}
.rec3{width:631.10px;height:469.44px}

.rec2:after,.rec3:after{width:0;height:0;border:0;content:'';position:absolute}
.rec2:after{
right:-167.26px;
border-left:167.26px solid #3F7F7D;
border-bottom:441.33px solid transparent;
}
.rec3:after{
right:-396.37px;
border-left:396.37px solid #3F7F7D;
border-top:469.44px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='cont1920 h23'>
    <div class='artw'>
      <div class='rec2'></div>
      <div class='rec3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try minifying your html as well during build. If we do indentation in HTML sometime some browsers add hairline space between them while rendering.

Comment: I will try that out, get back to you later!

Comment: It didnt help =/

Answer (score 0):

**Add some padding to** .rec2:after, .rec3:after

```
.rec2:after,.rec3:after{
   padding: 2px;
   width:0;
   height:0;
   border:0;
   content:'';
   position:absolute;
}
```

By the way, I don't recommend using width and height like you're doing in your css code, example: `width:631.10px; height:469.44px`, because if you want to make it responsive and perfect in all devices you should use `%` instead of `px`. I guess you're learning or/and trying something new.

Look this error when using px and when your design/page isn't using responsive design (and not using meta:viewport):
[image]

So there is white space and the design not fill the whole screen

Comment: It helped, but it got it all unaligned. I got like five more row of .rec and .rec:after.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,*:after,*:before,body{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
.row{width:100%;display:inline-flex}
.cont1920{width:100%;max-width:1920px;float:left;margin:auto;background:#8dbb70;position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.artw{width:1920px;position:absolute;left:40%;margin-left:-960px}
.h23{height:910.77px}

.rec2,.rec3{position:relative;background:#3F7F7D;content:''}
.rec2{width:631.10px;height:441.33px}
.rec3{width:631.10px;height:469.44px}

.rec2:after,.rec3:after{width:0;height:0;border:0;content:'';position:absolute}
.rec2:after{
right:-167.26px;
border-left:167.26px solid #3F7F7D;
border-bottom:441.33px solid transparent;
}
.rec3:after{
right:-396.37px;
border-left:396.37px solid #3F7F7D;
border-top:469.44px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='cont1920 h23'>
    <div class='artw'>
      <div class='rec2'></div>
      <div class='rec3'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It hides my undesired margin, but I doesn't resolve then. Also hiding it won't help in bigger devices.